# Finding $f_k(i)$ of $ (1, ~2i+1, ~3i, ~4i-2, ~5i-5, ~6i-9, ...) $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence of ($f_k(i)$) that goes like this

$$ f_0(i) =1, ~f_1(i)=2i+1...$$
$$ (1, ~2i+1, ~3i, ~4i-2, ~5i-5, ~6i-9, ...) $$

I'm not sure how to go about finding the general formula for this sequence?

Where would I start, is there even a sequence going on?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the recursive formula is 
$$f(k+1)=f(k)+i-(k-1)$$
for $k \ge 2$.

Comment: It would be true for $k \ge 1$ if the sequence with $i$, but it does not which is weird ... Is there anyway to make this explicit?

Answer (score 0):

From the pattern presented one form that produces the data is
\begin{align}
f_{k}(i) &= \begin{cases} 1 & k = 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} \, (k+1) (2 -k) + (k+1) \, i & k \geq 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
which also leads to the generating function
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f_{k}(i) \, t^{k} = \frac{1 - 2(1-i) \, t - 3 i \, t^{2} + i \, t^{3}}{(1-t)^{3}}.$$

This form leads directly to
$$f_{k+1}(i) = f_{k}(i) - k + i$$
for $k \geq 2$, which is the same as the difference equation given by Eric Fisher's answer.